# Error to hover items one by one in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need someone help me . I need when hover the image only select the image that i am over and not select all images that conteint the list. my code is :

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import intialState from '../../intialState';
import '../styles/components/banner.css';


const Banner = () => {
    const home = intialState.itemsHome;
    const [inHover, setHover] = useState(false);
    return (
        
        <div className="container h-100" >
            <div className="row align-middle">
            {home.map((items)=>{

               return (<div  id={items.id} class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 column"  onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)} >
               <div id={items.id}   class="card gr-1" style={{position:'absolute'}} >
                
                       <img  id={items.id} src={items.src} style={{position:'absolute'}}  className="image"  />
                        {inHover && <div  id={items.id} className="info" style={{position:'absolute'}}></div>}
                        
                       
       
                  
               </div>  
           </div>  );
               

             }) } 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Banner;
```

i need when hover the image only select image that i over.

thanks for you help.

Comment: You need to replace boolean state with image id state. No need to store boolean for hover or not hovering over the image. 

Simply you can do is, on 
`
MouseEnter={() => handleImageHover(item.id)}

const handleImageHover = (id) => {
  setHoverImageId(id)
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by use id instead of boolean to save selected image

```
const [inHover, setHover] = useState(null);

onMouseEnter={() => setHover(items.id)} onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}

{inHover === items.id && <div id={items.id} className="info" style={{position:'absolute'}}></div>}
```